# Merge multiple histograms into a single table and export as CSV

Tags: google-earth-engine, merge, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, histogram, imagecollection

I'm trying to merge multiple histograms of NDVI into a single table for future analysis
I know how to export and download single histogram like in the second image, but I'm aiming for something that will look like the first image where I did the merge manually
I'm looking for faster and easier way so I will get them merged with the date as a label automatically
I tried using Google Bard but I still have errors
the last one is
FeatureCollection (Error)
Error in map(ID=20230604T081609_20230604T082252_T36SXA):
Dictionary.get: Dictionary does not contain key: histogram.

```
var polygon = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[
  [34.8367106028781, 31.755708503828725],
  [34.83613124573088, 31.75163967813487],
  [34.83836284363127, 31.75098281058545],
  [34.839070946811205, 31.7557814856166]]]); 

var startDate = ee.Date('2023-06-01');
var endDate = ee.Date('2023-09-20');

var s2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")
  .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
  .filterBounds(polygon)

var NDVIimages = s2.map(function(image) {
    return image.addBands(image.normalizedDifference(['B8','B4']).rename('ndvi'))});

var S2_NDVI= NDVIimages.select('ndvi');  

function ndviHistogram(image) {
  var histogram = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.histogram({maxBuckets: 200, minBucketWidth: 0.01, maxRaw: 10}),
    // reducer: ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram(),
    geometry: polygon,
    scale: 10
  });
  
  // Extract the histogram properties directly
  var histogramData = ee.Dictionary({'histogram': histogram.get('histogram')});
  return ee.Feature(null, ee.Dictionary({
    'date': image.get('system:time_start'),
    'histogram': histogramData
  }));
}

// Map the histogram function over the Sentinel-2 collection
var ndviHistograms = S2_NDVI.map(ndviHistogram);

// Create a single FeatureCollection from the time series of histograms
var timeSeries = ee.FeatureCollection(ndviHistograms);

// Function to format the table header
function getTableHeader() {
  var header = ['NDVI Bucket (0.01 intervals)'];
  for (var i = 0; i < timeSeries.size(); i++) {
    header.push(timeSeries.get(i).get('date'));
  }
  return ee.List(header);
}

function formatFeatureData(feature) {
  var date = feature.get('date');
  var histogram = feature.get('histogram');
  // Check if 'histogram' exists and is a list before using it directly
  var data = histogram && histogram instanceof ee.List ? histogram : ee.List([]);  // Check if it's an ee.List
  // Fill missing values with zeros for consistent column length
  for (var i = 0; i < getTableHeader().length - 1; i++) {
    if (data.get(i) === undefined) {
      data = data.insert(i, 0);
    }
  }
return ee.Feature(null, {
    'date': date,
    'histogram_data': data
  });
}

var filteredTimeSeries = timeSeries.filter(ee.Filter.notNull(['histogram']));

var tableData = filteredTimeSeries.map(formatFeatureData);
print(tableData)

Export.table.toDrive(ee.FeatureCollection(tableData), 'ndvi_pixel_counts2', 'drive:', 'folder/ndvi_data');
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/7f74c275e347660c609995865ef019d2

[image: Manually merged histograms]

[image: Single histogram data downloaded]

Answer (score 2):

The error you're getting means that some of the images don't actually have any pixels inside the polygon. The easiest way to deal with that is to do the reduceRegion and just set the result back on the original image, and then filter out any images where histogram==null.  Something like:

```
function ndviHistogram(image) {
  var histogram = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: reducer,
    geometry: polygon,
    scale: 10
  });

  return image.set(histogram)
}
```

You also probably want to use a fixedHistogram instead of autoHistogram so every histogram uses the same buckets.  Then you can just add them together by getting them all with `aggregate_array`, turn them into an array, and then use `array.accum()`.

```
// Get the histograms, combine them into one big array and discard the bin centers.
var hists = ee.Array.cat(ndviHistograms.aggregate_array('ndvi'), 2).slice(1, -1)
// accumulate the counts, get the last value and flatten down to 1 axis.
var totals = hists.accum(2).slice(2, -1).project([0])
```

Comment: Thanks Noel, 
in the end I used fixed histogram and feature collection instead for arrays for export